# unable to get point cloud from /camera/depth/points in rviz

Tags: openni, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did :

```
rostopic echo /camera/depth/points
```

it seems topic is publishing messages. However, when i launch rviz- setting fixed frame to /camera_link or /camera_depth_frame or /camera_depth_optical_frame ( tried all seprately)

i get the following error when i subscribe to /camera/depth/points:

```
Transform= For frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame]: Frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame] does not exist
```

Any ideas on what am i doing wrong here ?

Also, point cloud data from /camera/depth_registered/points is currently displayed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44434/unable-to-get-point-cloud-from-/camera/depth/points-in-rviz/) by [trailblazer19](https://answers.ros.org/users/2726/trailblazer19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-09-23**:
Could you include the roslaunch command you are using to start up the driver?

**Comment by [trailblazer19](https://answers.ros.org/users/2726/trailblazer19/) on 2012-09-27**:
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

**Comment by [trailblazer19](https://answers.ros.org/users/2726/trailblazer19/) on 2012-09-27**:
@Boris   - i ran the echo frame_id command and got back /openni_rgb_optical_frame . I manually entered it in the Fixed frame under Global Options but it gives me frame does not exist error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When OpenNI publishes point cloud it sets up `frame_id` to some prespecified value, but it **does not** create a real `tf` frame. The `frame_id` simply says that points were acquired with respect to that frame.

To check the `frame_id` of your point cloud use the following command:

```
$ rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/depth/points/header/frame_id
```

Then, either manually fill in the value you get to **Fixed frame** in RViz or define a new `tf` transformation with [static_transform_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher), for example:

```
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 /world /openni_rgb_optical_frame 100
```

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-06-17**:
I did what you said but i still dont get a display on RVIZ, i still get the error For frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame]: Fixed Frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame ] does not exist